# Can "available as" be used to suggest another way to access an object?

Tags: prepositions, as

I tried to find an example from non-IT world, but failed. A technical description is as follows. I was trying to phrase it while working on an `angularjs` project. Consider the following sentence:

> Root scope is also available as `$root.$scope`.

To make it intelligible for non-programmers... There's an entity (a root scope) that one would occasionally want to use. One uses entities by specifying a name. There might be several ways to use (access) an entity (sort of, several names, or paths). By the way, if you know that you can make links to files, that might make more sense to you. But with a filesystem you'd probably use "also accessible/available at," and I think the analogy is not perfect. In my case it's about a way (method? approach?) to access an entity, rather than about a path (address).

What makes me doubt is that the closest [meaning of "as"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/as_1?q=as) I could find is:

> 1. used to describe somebody/something appearing to be somebody/something else 
>
>    They were all dressed as clowns. 
>    The bomb was disguised as a package.

Does "as" in the sentence sound okay? Should I use "via"? Or phrase it differently?

Comment: All your suggested options sound fine to me, though I'm only a hobbyist programmer, not a pro.

Comment: I'm an IT professional, and **as** sounds good to me.  *As* can mean something like "in the form of".

Comment: +1 for *as*. Maybe *accessible* or *addressable as*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is valid and common usage in software development.

An example in the physical world might be "This leaflet is also available as a poster", i.e. the content can be had in another form or via another medium.